# C++, function pointer to the template function pointer

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

I am having a pointer to the common static method

```
class MyClass
{
  private:
    static double ( *pfunction ) ( const Object *, const Object *);
    ...
};
```

pointing to the static method

```
 class SomeClass
 {
  public:
    static double getA ( const Object *o1, const Object *o2);
    ...
 };
```

Initialization:

```
double ( *MyClass::pfunction ) ( const Object *o1, const Object *o2 )  = &SomeClass::getA;
```

I would like to convert this pointer to the static template function pointer:

```
template <class T>
static T ( *pfunction ) ( const Object <T> *, const Object <T> *); //Compile error
```

where:

```
 class SomeClass
 {
  public:
    template <class T>
    static double getA ( const Object <T> *o1, const Object <T> *o2);
    ...
 };
```

But there is the following compile error:

```
error: template declaration of : T (* pfunction )(const Object <T> *o1, const Object <T> *o2)
```

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 24):

In the second case, `getA` is not a function anymore but a function *template*, and you can't have a pointer to function template.

What you can do is have `pfunction` point to a *particular `getA` instance* (ie: for `T = int`) :

```
class MyClass
{
    static double (*pfunction)(const Object<int> *, const Object<int> *);
};

double (*MyClass::pfunction)(const Object<int> *o1, const Object<int> *o2)  = &SomeClass::getA<int>;
```

But I don't think there is a way to get `pfunction` to point on *any* possible instance of `getA`.

Answer (score 14):

template is a **template** :) it's not a concrete type and cannot be used as a member. e.g. you cannot define following class:

```
class A
{
    template <class T> std::vector<T> member;
}
```

because `template <class T> std::vector<T> member;` is something that potentially can be specialized to many different types. you can do something like this:

```
template <class T>
struct A
{
 static T (*pfunction)();
};

struct B
{
 template <class T>
 static T getT();
};

int (*A<int>::pfunction)() = &B::getT<int>;
```

here `A<int>` is a specialized template and so has specialized member

Answer (score 9):

```
template <class T>
static T ( *pfunction ) ( const Object <T> *, const Object <T> *);
```

Template of function pointer is illegal in C++. Be it inside a class, or simply outside a class. You cannot write this (not even outside a class):

```
template <class X>
void (*PtrToFunction) (X);
```

See this sample : http://www.ideone.com/smh73

The C++ Standard says in $14/1,

> A template defines a family of **classes**
>   or **functions**.

Please note that it does NOT say "A template defines a family of *classes*, *functions* ***or function pointers***". So what you're trying to do is, defining "a family of function pointers" using template, which isn't allowed.

Generic Functors from [Loki](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/) library would be an elegant solution to the kind of problem you're having. :-)

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is have a copy of the template member function in the cpp file and point to that i.e.

```
template <+typename ElementType>
int PQueueHeap<ElementType>::compareFunction(ElementType First,ElementType Second)
{   
    if (First>Second) return 1; else if (First==Second) return 0; else return -1;
}

// you cannot point to above
```

however you can point to

```
template <+typename ElementType>

int compareFunction(ElementType First,ElementType Second)
{

if (First>Second) return 1; else if (First==Second) return 0; else return -1;
} // No error and it works!
```