# Pointer to template function which is NOT member of any class

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, typedef

I would like to have pointer to template function which has 2 parameters of type `T`.

```
template <typename T>
typedef bool( * f )( T, T );

template <typename T>
bool mniejsze (T pierwszy , T drugi){
    if( pierwszy < drugi)
        return true;
    return false;
}
template <typename T>
bool wieksze (T pierwszy, T drugi){
    if( pierwszy > drugi )
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

But I get:

```
 error: template declaration of 'typedef'|
```

**EDIT: Then I would like to pass that pointer:
Is it the right way?**

```
template <typename T>
T minmax(T a[], int n,bool &f){
    return f(a[0],a[1]);

}
```

Comment: C++11 support?   Do you understand you will get a `template` type, and to get the pointer you will have to supply `T`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ template typedef](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795023/c-template-typedef)

Comment: @MatthiasB It is not duplicate I ask about pointer not template function.

Comment: Have you tried the approaches in the link and they didn't work? It should be the same concept for template functions and pointer to template functions

Comment: @MatthiasB My template functions WORK, pointer does not.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573941/c-function-pointer-to-the-template-function-pointer you can't have a plain old pointer to *any* template function, just concrete type function pointer.

Comment: Have you try `template <typename T> using f = bool(*)(T, T);` ?

Comment: As you can see in the answers, these are the exact solutions of the duplicate I posted. The problem is that you are trying to typedef a Template, not that you are trying to typedef a function pointer. You can see a online working example here: https://ideone.com/jaFUrB

Comment: OUTSIDE THE CLASS OR STRUCTURE!

Answer (score 2):

In C++11 you can use aliases:

```
template<typename T>
using f = bool( *)( T, T );
```

usage:

```
f<int> f1 = wieksze;
f1( 3, 4);
```

http://ideone.com/KyUjwP

In C++03 there is a workoround:

```
template<typename T>
struct f {
    typedef bool( *type)( T, T );
};
```

usage:

```
f<int>::type  f1 = mniejsze<int>;
f<int>::type  f2 = mniejsze<int>;
f1( 3, 4);

template<typename T>
T minmax(T a[], int n, typename f<T>::type fp ){ 
    if ( fp( a[0], a[1])) return 1;
    return -1;
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    f<int>::type  f1 = wieksze<int>;
    bool b = f1( 3, 4);
    int a[] = { 3, 4};
    std::cout << minmax<int>( a, 0, f1);
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/Dh2eEN

Comment: Thank you very much but how to pas it then to the function:
This does not work very well
`T minmax(T a[], int n, &f){
}`

Comment: @Yoda I have provided an example for C++03

Answer (score 1):

In C++11 you can do:

```
template<class T>
using f = bool(*)(T, T);
```

And use:

```
f<int> fp = wieksze;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about the following?

```
 template <typename T>
  struct FNPTR {
    typedef bool (*f)( T, T );
 };
```

Put a dummy wrapper of a struct, and use FNPTR::f later?
For example,

```
FNPTR::f = mniejsze<char>;
```

This should work!

Comment: You mean `FNPTR<char>::f f = mniejsze<char>;`?

Comment: @Jarod42, Yes just as an example of template instantiation using char type, I meant FNPTR<char>::f f = mniejsze<char>;