# Resolve variadic argument to function pointer

Tags: c++, templates, arguments, c++17, variadic

Windows 10, Visual Studio 2019, C++17:

Compile error:
cannot convert argument 2 from 'int (__cdecl *)(int)' to '...'

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This is the templated function that becomes a variadic argument
//
template <typename siz> 
int func(siz size)
{
    // ...
    // ...
    return 0;
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This is the function that uses variadic arguments
//
int usefunc(int option, ...)
{
    // ...
    // ...
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int result;

    result = usefunc(0, func); // ** int usefunc(int,...)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'int (__cdecl *)(int)' to '...' **
                               // Context does not allow for disambiguation of overloaded function
    return result;
}
```

Without the template (int func(int size) ) the code compiles ok. How do I modify this to make the compiler understand the variadic argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is `func` is being treated as a function pointer, but [pointers to template functions are not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573941/c-function-pointer-to-the-template-function-pointer) in C++.

You need to specify the type you plan to use when you reference `func`, like:

```cpp
result = usefunc(0, func<int>);
```

You can use `decltype` to reference the type of a variable, to be a little more flexible:

```cpp
result = usefunc(0, func<decltype(result)>);
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for. Awarding bounty.